# XSL sum is not showing correct value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I need to sum the values of the XML fields below where final value should be 335.

```
<charges>
    <fees>25</fees>
    <service>
        <servtypes>Service 1</servtypes>
        <servamt>150</servamt>
    </service>
    <service>
        <servtypes>Service 2</sertypes>
        <servamt>10</servamt>
    </service>
    <service>
        <servtypes>Service 3</servtypes>
        <servamt>150</servamt>
    </service>
<charges>
```

This is a piece of XSL code which I use to display the data. The problem is if I include the sum function which is supposed to sum all servamt it gives me NaN value.
How can you fix it? Also how can I add fees on the sum of all servamt?

```
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell display-align="center">
<fo:block>Fees</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block><xsl:value-of select="fees"/></fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell display-align="center">
<fo:block><fo:leader/></fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>

<xsl:for-each select="service">
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell display-align="center">
<fo:block><xsl:value-of select="servtypes"/></fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell >
**<fo:block><xsl:value-of select="sum((charges/fees | service/servamt))"/>**</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell display-align="center">
<fo:block><fo:leader/></fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You are doing summing `seramt` nodes, but in your XML it is `servamt` (with a "v")

Comment: Also, note when you do the `sum` you are positioned on a `service` node, so doing `sum(servamt)` will only sum the `servamt` nodes under that `service` node. If you only have one such node, you don't really need to use sum.

Answer (score 2):

In the template rule that matches the parent element of your `fees` and `service` elements, call

```
sum((fees | service/servamt))
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for answering, I tried your suggesting (see my edit) but its zero.

Comment: Then you did something wrong, and if you want help finding out what, you will have to show us exactly what you did. Perhaps it was another spelling mistake like in your original post.

Comment: sum() is a function that applies to a set of numbers, you don't want to call it once for each of those numbers. You need to move the call out of that loop. Moreover, you've got to think about context. The set of numbers you want to sum() is given by the expression `fees|service/servamt` *provided that the context item is the `charges` element*. In your (revised) code the context item is a `service` element.

Answer (score 1):

In case when your XML will be as below (as in your it looks like root element is missing):

```
<root>
    <fees>25</fees>
    <service>
        <sertypes>Service 1</sertypes>
        <servamt>150</servamt>
    </service>
    <service>
        <sertypes>Service 2</sertypes>
        <servamt>10</servamt>
    </service>
    <service>
        <sertypes>Service 3</sertypes>
        <servamt>150</servamt>
    </service>
</root>
```

Then your code will work with below calculation in XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
                    <fo:block>Fees</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/root/fees"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:leader/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/service">
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="sertypes"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell >
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="sum(//servamt) + /root/fees"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:leader/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:table-row xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
        <fo:block>Fees</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>25</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
        <fo:block>
            <fo:leader/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
        <fo:block>Service 1</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>335</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
        <fo:block>
            <fo:leader/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
        <fo:block>Service 2</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>335</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
        <fo:block>
            <fo:leader/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
        <fo:block>Service 3</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>335</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell display-align="center">
        <fo:block>
            <fo:leader/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Hope it will help.